# How to unmarshal JSON into durations?

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling, duration

What is the idiomatic way to unmarshal into `time.Duration` in Go? How can I make use of `time.ParseDuration`?

Comment: For types defined outside of your project that do not implement the Unmarshaler interface, or do but in a way that is not sufficient for your requirements, you should define a "wrapper" type and have it implement the Unmarshaler interface so that it meets your needs.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The lack of JSON marshaling and unmarshaling methods on `time.Duration` was an unfortunate oversight. This should hopefully be resolved in Go2 ([see issue #10275](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/10275)).

You can, however, define your own type around `time.Duration` that supports marshaling to the string representation of the duration and unmarshaling from either the numeric or string representations. Here is an example of such an implementation:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Duration struct {
    time.Duration
}

func (d Duration) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(d.String())
}

func (d *Duration) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    var v interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &v); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    switch value := v.(type) {
    case float64:
        d.Duration = time.Duration(value)
        return nil
    case string:
        var err error
        d.Duration, err = time.ParseDuration(value)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        return nil
    default:
        return errors.New("invalid duration")
    }
}

type Message struct {
    Elapsed Duration `json:"elapsed"`
}

func main() {
    msgEnc, err := json.Marshal(&Message{
        Elapsed: Duration{time.Second * 5},
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", msgEnc)

    var msg Message
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"elapsed": "1h"}`), &msg); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", msg)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Zm6hpNR-ZJ2

Comment: Why is it float64 not int64?

Comment: Because the JSON package unmarshals numbers into `interface{}` as `float64`.

Comment: why is `Duration` a `struct` of  `time.Duration` instead of as in the other answer: i.e. `type Duration time.Duration`? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: One thing I noticed when implementing this solution but with a type alias was that you lose some of the access to existing methods on the `time.Duration` type. So one example was that when implementing `MarshalJSON` the `String` method no longer existed.

Answer (score 31):

Just to extend the previous answer. There is another way (very close to Tim's)

```
type Duration time.Duration 

func (d Duration) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(time.Duration(d).String())
}

func (d *Duration) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    var v interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &v); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    switch value := v.(type) {
    case float64:
        *d = Duration(time.Duration(value))
        return nil
    case string:
        tmp, err := time.ParseDuration(value)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        *d = Duration(tmp)
        return nil
    default:
        return errors.New("invalid duration")
    }
}
```